# What does a closed loop mean in Kirchhoff's voltage law?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]

Is $\underline{A}CDF\underline{A}$ a closed loop?

Comment: Easier to consider ABEF and BCDE as the two closed loops.

Comment: @josephh I understand, but what is the definition of a closed-loop? Does ACDFA fall under that definition?

Comment: Yes it is a closed loop, but know that you can't solve the problem without analyzing each smaller loop first.

Comment: This not true. You can pick the large loop and one of the smaller loops.  It does not matter which loops you pick. Just to have the right number of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a closed loop. Essentially what you want to achieve with a closed loop is get back to the same point you started from. Any path that achieves that is by definition a closed loop.

An electric charge travelling in the circuit feels electromagnetic forces and these forces either do work on the charge (eg battery cell) or the charge does work on them (eg resistor). The total work done by the charge is equal the total work on the charge as it goes around and comes back to the same point.

We can parallel this with a ball moving up and down a curved 1-dimensional hill. If we want to reach the same height as we started from, then the amount we go down must equal the amount we go up, by definition. The latter point is regardless of the path we take, it only depends on the fact that the end points have the same height.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A loop is a closed path inside a circuit. A closed-loop in Kirchoff's law means that you can come back to the starting node while traversing through the nodes of the loop. For example, $ABEFA$, $BCDEB$ and $ACDFA$ are the loops in the given circuit. You can find out the number of nodes, branches and loops using the basic theorem of network topology:

$$b = l+n-1$$

where $b$ is the number of branches, $l$ is the number of loops and $n$ is the number of nodes.